# Filtering products depends user choice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I got product page with option to filter by size\model\price and sort.

I did succeed make this work but with like 5-6 useEffect and it looks very massy.

I need some hints on how to make it work without 5-6 useEffects because I tried really hard and didnt make it.

I am using redux toolkit .

So filters values are coming from redux-store

```
  const { size, brand, price, sort } = useSelector((state) => state.filter);
```

products data coming from my backend

```
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS);
```

and this is how I did it with so many use effects...

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (sort.length > 0) {
      if (sort.includes('price-highest')) {
        setFilteredProducts((filteredList) =>
          filteredList.slice().sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price)
        );
      } else {
        setFilteredProducts((filteredList) =>
          filteredList.slice().sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)
        );
      }
    }
  }, [data?.getProducts, sort, size, brand, price]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (size.length > 0) {
      setFilteredProducts((list) =>
        list.filter((product) => {
          return product.size.includes(Number(...size));
        })
      );
    }
  }, [data?.getProducts, data, size, brand, price]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (brand.length > 0) {
      setFilteredProducts((list) =>
        list.filter((product) => {
          return product.brand.includes(...brand);
        })
      );
    }
  }, [data?.getProducts, brand, size, price]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (price.length > 0) {
      setFilteredProducts((list) =>
        list.filter((product) => {
          return product.price > price[0][0] && product.price < price[0][1];
        })
      );
    }
  }, [data?.getProducts, price, brand, size]);
```

redux filters:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is nothing wrong about putting everything in one effect. The only benefit of using multiple effects with different dependency arrays is, that in case only one parameter changes, some operations can be skipped.

But I think that is not true for your use case, since if one filter parameter changes, you have to re-calculate all filters and sort again. The only benefit you have would be to avoid re-filtering if only sort parameters change.

Even then, the performance gains of using multiple effects would likely be neglectable. The product list comes from the backend, so I think we can safely assume it is not huge - maybe hundreds of elements, but not millions or billions. The filter operations are cheap and we can perform the sort step last.

So just use one `useEffect` hook with the combined dependencies.

```js
 useEffect(() => {

    const applySort = (filteredList) => (sort.length === 0)
       ? filteredList
       : sort.includes('price.highest') 
       ? filteredList.slice().sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price)
       : filteredList.slice().sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
       
    const sizePredicate = (product) => (size.length === 0) 
      || product.size.includes(Number(...size));
        
    const brandPredicate = (product) => (brand.length === 0)
       || product.brand.includes(Number(...brand));

    const pricePredicate = (product) => (price.length === 0)
       || product.price > price[0][0]   
       && product.price < price[0][1];
 
    setFilteredProducts(
      applySort(
        data.getProducts()
          .filter(sizePredicate)
          .filter(brandPredicate)
          .filter(pricePredicate)
        )
      );
  
  }, [data.getProducts(), sort, price, brand, size]);
```

Comment: I just got one problem with this solution , I am having hard time to understand since the function is not wrapped inside {} and when I try to wrap I got some errors

Comment: You can wrap the function calls in {} if you like and add a return statement. Maybe the last predicate is wrong - if I have time I'll check it again. Meanwhile, you can also modify my code and use your own functions from your example, it should make no big difference

Comment: Everything working perfectly. thank you sir